# Promises and React Native Assistance

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need help understanding promises in React Native I honestly get the basic Idea but could someone help me explain in more depth.

I took a look at Node promises Javascript promises on Mozilla, but I think its the way I am doing it that is the problem.

If you do help please dont just simply give me the Answer I would like to understand "why"

I have two methods. "WORKER PAGE"

and a call from any other page "OTHER PAGE"

WORKER PAGE

```
var Server_Ip = 'http://0.0.0.0:0000/'
let fetching = false;


exports.POST = function (url, data) {
  if (fetching) return Promise.reject({D: 5});
  fetching = true;
  fetch(Server_Ip + url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then(response => Promise.all([response.json()]))
    .then(([response]) => {
      fetching = false;
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("error catch search:", err.message);
      fetching = false;
      // Choose one, depends what you need.
      return {D: 0}; 
      return Promise.reject(err); 
    })
 }
```

then I do a call from another page

```
Wkr.POST(string, data_send).then(response => {

                console.log('response');
                console.log(response);

                //9 - SIGN IN PASSWORD MATCHES
                if (response.D == 9) {
                    alert("YAY! GO THRU")
                }
                //8 - PASSWORDS DONT MATCH
                else if (response.D == 8) {
                    alert("SORRY!, THE PASSWORDS DONT MATCH")
                }
                //7 - NO SUCH USER
                else if (response.D == 7) {
                    alert("SORRY!, NO SUCH USER")
                }
                //6 - EMAIL IS NOT VALIDATED
                else if (response.D == 6) {
                    alert("SORRY!, EMAIL IS NOT VALIDATED")
                }
                //5 - YOU HAVE TRIED TO LOGIN
                else if (response.D == 5) {
                    alert("YOU HAVE TRIED TO LOGIN, PLEASE DONT SPAM")
                }
                //0 - ERROR
                else if (response.D == 0) {
                    alert("ERROR");
                } else {
                    alert("SHOULD NOT BEEN HERE");
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
```

So I have purposely messed with the IP of the server to to simulate a possible issue and it doesnt do much but as I spam it returns

```
[16:39:21] Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[16:39:21] Object {
[16:39:21]   "D": 5,
[16:39:21] }
[16:39:21]
```

which to my understanding is being handled and should hit if statement "5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the `then` callback in your other page does not deal with a rejection, namely the one you generated with `Promise.reject`. To deal with that rejection, you should chain a `.catch` callback in the other page:

```
.then(response => { // This is called when the promise was fulfilled
     ......
}).catch(reason => { // This is called when the promise was rejected
    if (reason.D == 5) {
        alert("YOU HAVE TRIED TO LOGIN, PLEASE DONT SPAM")
    }
    .....
});
```

Another thing: in the worker page your function does not return a promise (except for the rejection case). You need to *return* what `fetch` returns:

```
return fetch(Server_Ip + url, {
^^^^^^^
```

In the worker page you also have some code that you did not finish:

```
  // Choose one, depends what you need.
  return {D: 0}; 
  return Promise.reject(err);
```

... You need to choose. You cannot have both. Which one you choose will determine in which of the above handlers (the `then` or `catch` handler) this case will end up. Note also that `return Promise.reject(err)` is not much different from just `throw err` (in the context of a `then/catch` callback or promise constructor callback).

Comment: thank you for the reply. I know most people feel its a stupid question but If i dont understand something I need to know why.

so on any promise that is created the only way to handle a reject is through a catch? because the method is already in a Try Catch.

Comment: The reason im asking is because i have seen some methods with resolve, reject next to each other.. maybe thats why i am getting confused.

Comment: `try/catch` and `.catch` do different things. A rejected promise is not an exception, but if you do not handle it, the engine will warn you by generating an unhandled rejection exception. But yes, `.catch` is used to do something when a promise was rejected. `.then` (first argument) is used to do something when a promise was fulfilled.

Comment: `resolve` and `reject` functions only play a role when you have to create a promise from scratch. It is not your case, since you already get one with `fetch`.